# mySQL Select multiple rows more than once based on date

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I need to select the rows more than once based on dates ascending.

Example Table:

Program   | Date1           |  Date2 
Fun run    |  2013-10-01   | 2013-11-06
Fun walk  |  2013-09-01    | 2013-09-03
Fun jog    |   2013-11-01   | 2013-11-04

To display :

2013-09-01  | Fun walk
2013-09-03  | Fun walk
2013-10-01  | Fun run
2013-11-01  | Fun jog
2013-11-04  | Fun jog
2013-11-06  | Fun run

Select Date1, Date2 From Example Table Sort ASC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SELECT** date1 as date, program **FROM** table **UNION ALL SELECT** date2 as date, program **FROM** table **ORDER BY** date, program

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the cookie. I'd be even happier with an accept & upvote ;-)

Comment: I can't up vote till i have 15 rep that's why i gave you a cookie sorry.